# Dynamically generated JS + Flexbox rectangular grid does not display correctly certain sizes on Firefox desktop

Tags: javascript, css, flexbox

I have a function that dynamically creates a grid with a rectangular aspect ratio.
It works without problems on Chromium and DDG (mobile), but not on Firefox desktop.
For certain sizes ( 7, 11, 17, 19, 26, 28, ...) the bottom row displays as a single div running along the width of the grid container.

I tried adding `min-height: 0;` or `min-height: auto;` to the container or the divs inside it. It didn't work. I tried the same with `min-width` and still negative.

https://jsfiddle.net/heyjs/k68oxrLy/28/

The jsfiddle here also displays the grid correctly on the above mentioned browsers, but not on Firefox (v. 108.0) for desktop.
I expect it to display rectangular divs of equal size.

Comment: You're using flexbox to try to make a grid, but flexbox is only really made for rows. It can be done, but as you've discovered there are some issues. CSS grid was made to address these deficiencies. To address your problem, try adding a `min-width` CSS property to your `.grid-container div`.

Comment: @Josh, thanks for replying, `min-width` doesn't seem to be working, I've tried it with different values and the elongated div is still there in Firefox. Will probably switch to grid if I don't find a solution in reasonable time. Cheers.

Comment: Sorry, I meant `max-width`. My mistake.

Comment: @Josh, I tried with several `max-width` values and it didn't work. The suggested solution to add `gridPixel.style.flexBasis = Math.floor(600 / divNumber) + 'px';` instead of `gridPixel.style.flexBasis = 600 / divNumber + 'px';` worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this in your code, it's a division issue:

`gridPixel.style.flexBasis = Math.floor(600 / divNumber) + 'px';`

Or you can go with `Mat.ceil` (86px) or `Math.round` (86px, as well).